# Converting dates in Excel from YYYYMMDD format to something easier work with

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm copying and pasting large amounts of data including dates in the YYYYMMDD format with no separators. Is there a way to format the cells or even run a macro to convert the numbers into a readable date that Excel will recognize?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us from where you are copying the data and what data you might have besides the dates. Maybe the data can be modified before pasting into Excel. You could also use a separate column with a formula to calculate a date from the numbers in the cells you have pasted.

Comment: Answer readily found online: https://www.excel-exercise.com/convert-date-yyyymmdd-to-dd-mm-yyyy-without-formula/